# Sql 2016 - How to get only modified column in system-versioned temporal table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

How to get only modified column in system-versioned temporal table.

I am using SQL 2016 system-versioned temporal table to track the changes. I have the history table populated with multiple rows which include modified and not modified columns for each version of row edit.

Is there any way to get only modified column value from history row data.

Appreciated your response.

Thanks

Abdul

Comment: Appreciate any help - Thank you!

Comment: you may be looking for `DML Trigger`

Comment: Hi @LONG , I have all data (modified as well as Not modified), Might be I may to use Vlookup from history data

Comment: @LONG when using system versioned temporal table, you do not need the DML triggers for solving the abovementioned problems. Check this for sample code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60279554/1666800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this approach to solve the problem.

1. Fetch all history and transaction records and Partitioned with Primary key.
2. Cross Apply the table to make row structure is Column Name and Column Value and of course other IDs like Primary Key, Partitioned Key, etc
3. Compare Column value based on Column Name, Primary key and Partition Key

Please let me know if any good approach.

Regards
Abdul

Comment: Hi Abdul
I have a very similar requirement, can you please share your t-sql?

I was thinking of using the LAG function to compare with previous row but might be a bit clunky

Comment: @JanFeyen check this for sample code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60279554/1666800

Comment: Hi @JanFeyen -  I saw your message today :). I hope you got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Abdul Azeez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50359126/1666800) description, here is the sample code to achieve this goal:

Suppose that I have a table called `MyTable`, and I want to capture the changes on `Name` and `LastName` columns(both have varchar data type) **FOR ALL** the time.

```
;WITH T
AS (
    SELECT ID,
           LAG(Name) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SysStartTime, SysEndTime) AS Prev_Name,
           Name,
           LAG(LastName) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SysStartTime, SysEndTime) AS Prev_LastName,
           LastName,
           Email,
           SysStartTime,
           SysEndTime
    FROM dbo.MyTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
    WHERE Email = 'myEmail@somewhere.com'
)
SELECT T.SysStartTime,
       T.SysEndTime,
       C.ColName,
       C.prev_value,
       C.cur_value
FROM T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        VALUES
            ('Name', T.Name, T.Prev_Name),
            ('LastName', T.LastName, T.Prev_LastName)
    ) AS C (ColName, cur_value, prev_value)
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT cur_value 
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT C.prev_value
);
```

**Note:** If the columns have different data types you might need to cast them to an appropriate data type.